# Scatter plot change plot output when more scatters are added

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-science, scatter-plot

*A brief into on what i am working on.* I am trying to make a plot from a scanned image. I have managed to turn the image to black and white and after that i made two **csv** files. The first one contains  all the white values coordinates from the image (x,y) and the second file contains all the black coordinates. So the idea is that if i plot the the black coordinates i would get a similar plot like the image but with scatters.

Let me give some examples. 
Let's say that this is the black and white image 
[image]

If i plot both black and white coordinates like that

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.scatter(y, centered_y, s=0.5, c='r', marker='o', label='Background')
ax1.scatter(a, b, s=0.5, c='b', marker='o', label='black')
ax1 = plt.gca()
ax1.set_ylim(-300, 300)
ax1.set_xlim(0, 2000)
ax1.set_ylim(ax1.get_ylim()[::-1])
ax1.set_yticks(ticks=[-200, 0, 200])
ax1.set_xticks(ticks=[0, 1500, 2000])
```

i get a descent plot, which is quite close to the original image.
[image]

The problem that i have, is when i am trying to plot only one pair of scatter coordinates (either black coordinates or white coordinates). For example if i plot only the white coordinates i get this kind of plot (it is a bit zoomed in), which that too is quite close to the original image. [image] The problem is when i am tryng to plot only the black coordinates, i supposed that i would get the 'negative' of the previous plot as we can see in the blue and red graph (first plot). Unfortunatelly i get this :  [image] and if i order the x axis i get this : [image].

What i am trying to do is to connect the scatters of the black coordinates with a line so the plot to seems like the scanned image, but as i explained i can't get the right plot when i plot only the black coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time i found out that i was sorting only one of both axis.

The **solution** was to create a Dataframe and sort it on x axis. 
I was pretty silly :)